# Storing schema name as a variable in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to avoid using PGSQL for some simple queries, but I want to store the schema name as a variable and use it later in multiple queries:

```
WITH p AS (SELECT 'testSchema' AS schemaName)
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS p.schemaName;
create table if not exists p.schemaName.table1;
```

Perhaps "with" is not the right way, or may by I need to use it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the SQL statement `SET`, perhaps with the `LOCAL` option, but that won't work with `CREATE SCHEMA`.

Something like this:

```
BEGIN;  -- start transaction
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS testschema;
SET LOCAL search_path = 'testschema';  -- only for this transaction
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 ...; -- will be created in testschema
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I finally used: SET LOCAL search_path = 'schema1', 'schema2'; as i needed more than 1 schema in my script.

Comment: But, if for some reason the command line is more acceptable to you than pl/pgsql (dynamic sql procedures), then you could set schemas in create views with a variable: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/172684/179926.